# Adding materialUI circular progress bar over the circular icon

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add circular progress bar surrounding a circular icon with a space between circular progress bar and icon just like shown in the image below.
I was able to position the  circular progress bar around the icon but couldn't able to give space between them.
How can i do that.

[image]
How i want

[image]

How i am getting

**Here is my code** :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Grid, Paper, Box, CircularProgress, circularProgressClasses } from '@mui/material';

const MileStones = () => {
    return (
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, position: 'relative', display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', pl: 2 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={1.4} sx={{ py: 4 }}>
          <Grid item xs >
            <CircularProgress size={50} sx={{ color: '#C4C4C4', position: 'absolute' }} variant="determinate" value={100} />
            <Paper sx={{ background: '#162983', width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: '50%'}}></Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs>
          <CircularProgress size={50} sx={{ position: 'absolute' }} variant="determinate" value={25} />
          <Paper elevation={3} sx={{ background: '#162983', width: 50, height: 50, textAlign: "center", borderRadius: '50%'}}></Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs>
          <CircularProgress size={50} sx={{ position: 'absolute' }} variant="determinate" value={25} />
          <Paper elevation={3} sx={{ background: '#162983', width: 50, height: 50, textAlign: "center", borderRadius: '50%'}}></Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs>
          <CircularProgress size={50} sx={{ position: 'absolute' }} variant="determinate" value={25} />
          <Paper elevation={3} sx={{ background: '#162983', width: 50, height: 50, textAlign: "center", borderRadius: '50%'}}></Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs>
          <CircularProgress size={50} sx={{ position: 'absolute' }} variant="determinate" value={25} />
          <Paper elevation={3} sx={{ background: '#162983', width: 50, height: 50, textAlign: "center", borderRadius: '50%'}}></Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        .
        .
        .
        .


        </Grid>
      </Box>
    )
}

export default MileStones
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Consider that space being a thin circle with a white background, instead.

Comment: You should ask a question using a comment not an answer.

Comment: That was an implicit answer. I'll do that anyway. Thanks

Comment: Try to write a good answer. There could be more helpful code or idea what you think. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer